knitting selected sections of an R Markdown
I'm using R to work my way through some homework questions- I need to upload a document for each specific question. Is there a way to use knit to render a specific parameter? for example in my reprex below, lets say I just want to knit chunk# 2 to an html and exclude chunk 1
---
title: "reprex"
author: "John Doe"
date: "2024-07-12"
output: html_document
df_print: paged
params:
  printcode: true  
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)



Chunk 1 dataframe and plot: 

```{r, include= FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
# Define the age groups and corresponding incidence rates
age_groups <- c("20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79", "80-89")
incidence_rates <- c(NA, NA, 45, 40, 36, 31, 27)  # NA for unknown rates
# Calculate midpoint of age groups for plotting
age_midpoint <- c(24.5, 34.5, 44.5, 54.5, 64.5, 74.5, 84.5)
# Create dataframe
data <- data.frame(age_groups, incidence_rates, age_midpoint)

#plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = age_midpoint, y = incidence_rates)) +
  geom_line(color = "skyblue", size = 1) +  # line plot
  geom_point(color = "skyblue", size = 3) +  # add points for visibility
  labs(title = "Incidence Rate of Breast Cancer by Age Group (Colorado, 2010)",
       x = "Age Group (Midpoint)", y = "Incidence Rate per 1,000") +
  ylim(0, 50) +  # set y-axis limit
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) 

chunk 2 dataframe and plot:
# Define the age groups and corresponding incidence rates for each survey year
age_groups <- c("20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79", "80-89")
incidence_1980 <- c(NA, 14, 12, 10, NA, NA, NA)
incidence_1990 <- c(NA, 23, 19, 18, 15, NA, NA)
incidence_2000 <- c(NA, 35, 40, 36, 32, 30, NA)
incidence_2010 <- c(NA, 45, 40, 40, 36, 31, 27)
# Calculate midpoint of age groups for plotting
age_midpoint <- c(24.5, 34.5, 44.5, 54.5, 64.5, 74.5, 84.5)
# Create dataframe
data <- data.frame(age_groups, incidence_1980, incidence_1990, incidence_2000, incidence_2010, age_midpoint)

#plot the data

data_long <- gather(data, key = "year", value = "incidence_rate", -age_groups, -age_midpoint)

# Plot using ggplot2
ggplot(data_long, aes(x = age_midpoint, y = incidence_rate, color = year)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +  # line plot
  geom_point(size = 3) +  # add points for visibility
  labs(title = "Incidence Rate of Breast Cancer by Age Group (Colorado, Historical Data)",
       x = "Age Group (Midpoint)", y = "Incidence Rate per 1,000",
       color = "Survey Year") +
  ylim(0, 50) +  # set y-axis limit
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))




I've tried using printcode=true. I was expecting this to print chunks i identified as "true" and exclude chunk i id'd as "false"

